# Get some date from table one and update by a form with other data and update in another table >

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Id(primary key)  name     age     option

01               shuvo     23     update mark
02               axiom     24     update mark
03               john      25     update mark
```

I want to update mark from there and when I do it I can retrieve the id and get info like below

```
id      subject            mark      

01      math              50
02      math              80
03      math              90
```

### last the data output will be

### name        subject     mark

How do I write query in MySQL and php?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to add foreign key in 2nd table and then
use SQL join for fetching records.

Answer (score 0):

> Table1: Student
>   Id(primary key)    name       age       option
>
> 01               shuvo       23       update mark
>    02               axiom       24       update mark
>    03               john        25       update mark
>
> Table2: Marks
>    id        FK_ID    subject            mark
>
> 01          1       math              50
>   02          1       math              80
>   03          2       math              90

Query:
Select name,subject, mark from Student, Marks where Student.Id = Marks.FK_ID;

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.